# In java, how can I delete a sqlite table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am developing android app. I have to develop a xml button in my activity, and construct my sqlite database and tables. How can I just let user press a button to delete a table? Thanks.

Comment: Use `DROP TABLE "table_name"`. Example: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/117.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite: efficient way to drop lots of rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530419/sqlite-efficient-way-to-drop-lots-of-rows)

Answer (score 41):

Hard to answer without more context, but the ultimate sqlite query would be:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name");
```

Where db is a reference to a SqliteDatabase object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when I put the statement in the following paragraph, it still doesn't work:     public void onOpen(){

     
        Button next3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
      
        next3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         SQLiteDatabase db;
  
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) { 

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");


   } 
   });   
     
     
    }

Comment: You still need to have a valid reference to the db, which you would need to open first, here's a simple tutorial http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/. Though if you're wanting to do more with this eventually, you'll want to look at Content Providers.

Answer (score 18):

There is some ambiguity with your question. Note that there is a difference between **DELETING** a table and **DROPPING** a table. Deleting the table simply erases all data from its rows:

```
database.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
```

After this, you can still reference the table because it still exists, but creating a new one with the same name may be problematic without using the *CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS* expression in sql.

Using *DROP TABLE* completely removes the table and it cannot be referenced again unless it is re-created.

As noted by others, this should work if you want it completely removed from the database:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase sdb;
sdb=openOrCreateDatabase("dbname.db", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
sdb.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename");
```

Answer (score 0):

**As a Singleton method**

```
 // todo DELETE a special field(s)
public boolean deleteFromTable(int yurtId) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    final String whereClause = DBHelper.COLUMN_Y_YURT_ID + " =?";
    final String whereArgs[] = {String.valueOf(yurtId)};
    int affectedRows = database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME_YEMEKCI, whereClause, whereArgs);
    return affectedRows > 0;
}

  // todo DELETE all table 
public boolean deleteTable() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    int affectedRows = database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME_YEMEKCI, null, null);
    return affectedRows > 0;
}
```