# SQLite: efficient way to drop lots of rows

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

SQlite, Android, true story. I have a table, which I use as a cache:

```
CREATE TABLE cache(key TEXT, ts TIMESTAMP, size INTEGER, data BLOB);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX by_key ON cache(key);
CREATE INDEX by_ts ON cache(ts);
```

During app lifetime I fill the cache and at some point I want to clear it out and drop `N` records. Typically this table will contain ~25000 blobs ~100-500Kb each, total blobs size in the DB is 600-800Mb, but now I test for ~2000 which are about 60Mb (following numbers are for this case). Clear removes 90% of cache entries.

**I tried different ways to do it, here brief description:**

**[1]** Worst and simplest. First select, than remove one by one, walking cursor. Terribly slow.

**[2]** Make SQLite to do it with query (delete blobs with totally `N` bytes in them):

```
DELETE FROM blobs WHERE
  ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID FROM blobs WHERE 
             (SELECT SUM(size) FROM blobs AS _ WHERE ts <= blobs.ts) <= N);
```

This is faster, but still terribly slow: ~15 sec. Seems also it like it has quadratic complexity.

**[3]** Select row around where to remove (using average blob size for computations) and delete with simple `WHERE` clause:

```
-- Find row after which to delete, let it's time stamp is T0:
SELECT ts FROM cache ORDER BY ts LIMIT 1 OFFSET count;
-- Delete
DELETE FROM cache WHERE ts < T0;
```

This is much better, but takes ~7 sec.

**[4]** Create new table, copy that I need to save and drop old one. Note, that I create index in the new table AFTER I copied all this stuff:

```
  -- Insert only rows I want leave
  INSERT INTO temp(key, ts, size, data) SELECT key, ts, size, data 
    FROM cache ORDER BY ts LIMIT count;
  -- Drop table and indices.
  DROP INDEX by_key;
  DROP INDEX by_ts;
  DROP TABLE cache;
  -- Rename temp table and create indices...
```

Copying takes ~300ms for 6Mb for blobs. But `DROP TABLE` is about ~8 sec.

Note in all cases I do `VACUUM` which takes another ~1 sec. How can I make it fast? Why `DROP TABLE` and deletion are so slow? I think it might be because of indices: when I dropped key index before `DELETE` it worked faster. How to make SQLite delete fast?

Comment: What if you drop in a thread.  then it won't affect the user.. Not ideal I suppose.

Comment: NOTE: Creating an index before insert, or after insert, takes about the same amount of time. It still has to index.

Comment: Actually, surrounding `DELETE` in transaction helped much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working on a database with "big" data - ie, each blob using multiple pages.

At some point near optimal performance you will reach a limit you can't improve.

Checking all your choices, I see different behaviors, not just different algorithms.

[1] This one shouldn't be terrible slow as long as you use a transaction. You need two operations at once, query (to get blob size) and delete.

[2] This is a good approach. As two queries and a delete, all in a single command, so SQLite engine will optimize.

[3] This is a different behaviour from all before. Same as `DELETE FROM cache WHERE ts < (SELECT ts FROM cache ORDER BY ts LIMIT 1 OFFSET count)`. Query is less expensive then previous, but I bet number of rows deleted are far less then previous one! Expensive part of query/delete will be delete! Query optimization is important, but things will always get slower in delete.

[4] This is a very bad approach!!! Copying all your data to a new table - maybe another database - will be VERY expensive. I only get one advantage from this: you may copy data to a new database and avoid `VACUUM`, as new database was build from base and it's clean.

About `VACUUM`... Worst then `DELETE` is `VACUUM`. Vacuum is not supposed to be used often in a database. I understand this algorithm is supposed to "clean" your database, but cleaning shouldn't be a frequent operation - databases are optimized for select/insert/delete/update - not to keep all data at a minimal size.

My choice would be using a `DELETE ... IN (SELECT ...)` single operation, according to predefined criteria. `VACUUM` wouldn't be used, at least not so often. One good choice would be monitor db size - when this size run over a limit, run a assumed expensive cleaning to trim database.

At last, when using multiple commands, never forget to use transactions!

Comment: Transactions for multiple statements are needed only if there are multiple changes; read-only transactions do not have a huge overhead.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, what is slow is not finding the records to be deleted, but the actual deletion itself.

Check if [PRAGMA secure_delete](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_secure_delete) is set by default in your Android's SQLite.
You should just disable it, just to be sure.

You do not need to run `VACUUM`; SQLite automatically resuses freed pages.
You need `VACUUM` only if you *actually know* that the database will not grow again in size in the future.

Comment: This changed a big DELETE from seconds to milliseconds for me.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options to improve the performance, especially the first one:

1) Using Transaction like this:

```
DbTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(); // <-------------------
try 
{
   Any code to delete the items
}
catch
{
    trans.Rollback(); // <-------------------
    throw; // <-------------------
}
```

2) Otherwise, supposing that the items are continuous, then

- a) Get the ID of the first item;
- b) Get the total number of items to be deleted
- c) Using command like this:

  `DELETE FROM blobs WHERE ID > fistId LIMIT count;`

Good luck.

Comment: Android has no `DbTransaction` object.

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault to confuse it with .NET environment.

For Android, I would use: SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction() and SQLITEDatabase.endTransaction().

The key point is that demi has tried to execute multiple SQL commands, and SQLite would always wrap each command as a separate transaction to lag the performance dramatically.