# In Java, How to Drop Sqlite Table

Tags: java, sqlite

hi i have tried this command on my sqlite database but it wont drop/delete my database table,
here my [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364194/in-java-how-can-i-delete-a-sqlite-table)

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sqlCommand = "DROP TABLE 'myTable' ";

System.out.println("output : " + stmt.executeUpdate(sqlCommand));

//Output
output : 0
```

there are no return error so i still cant figure by myself what is making the code not working.

Code to Drop Table

```
Connection c = null;
Statement stmt = null;
String sql;
c = openSqlite(c);         //method i create to setup sqlite database connection
stmt = c.createStatement();

try{
System.out.println("Deleting table in given database...");

String sqlCommand = "DROP TABLE 'myTable' ";

stmt.executeUpdate(sqlCommand);
System.out.println("Table  deleted in given database...");

stmt.close();
c.commit();
c.close();
}catch(SQLException se){
//Handle errors for JDBC
se.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the database to see if the table has actually been dropped?  As `executeUpdate` may return *"either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing"*

Comment: yes, and i have refresh my table several time but the table and it content is still exist..

Comment: use "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'myDatabase.myTable" in command line and check what happens

Comment: Also, make sure you either have autocommit enable or you commit the transaction...

Comment: i can delete my table now

Comment: i did not commit the transaction before

Comment: Is the name of the table really "`myDatabase.myTable`"? With the quotes, `myDatabase.` is part of the table name.

Comment: oh thank you.. actually only myTable not "myDatabase.myTable"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to MadProgrammer and other, Actually i miss to put commit statement on my code..

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sqlCommand = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'myDatabase.myTable' ";

System.out.println("output : " + stmt.executeUpdate(sqlCommand));

stmt.close();
conn.commit();     // commit after execute sql command
                //COMMIT TRANSACTION makes all data modifications performed since 
                //the start of the transaction a permanent part of the database, 
conn.close();
```